# I want to blink an image using a python code

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I created a white colored image matrix using numpy and now i want to blink any color over the right half of the image matrix that i created i am using the following code but it's not working as expected

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

i=0
img=np.zeros((400,800,3),np.uint8)
img.fill(255)
while(i<=1):
    img[0:400,400:800]=(153,0,255)
    cv2.imshow('package',img)
    time.sleep(5)
    img[0:400,400:800]=(255,255,255)
    cv2.imshow('package',img)
    time.sleep(5)
    img[0:400,400:800]=(153,0,255)
    cv2.imshow('package',img)
    i=i+1

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`

Comment: What happens when you use the current code? Something more specific than "no as expected".

Comment: when I run the current program, it waits for five seconds(displaying a grey colored window) and after five seconds it shows the image which I instructed it to in the end which in this case an image with left half white and right half pink in color.

Answer (score 0):

You need "waitkey" just after imshow to ensure image redraws. waitkey(5000) means 5 seconds wait. "time.sleep(5)" is not necessary here:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import time

    i=0
    img=np.zeros((400,800,3),np.uint8)
    img.fill(255)
    while(i<=1):
        img[0:400,400:800]=(153,0,255)
        cv2.imshow('package',img)
        cv2.waitKey(5000)        
        img[0:400,400:800]=(255,255,255)
        cv2.imshow('package',img)
        cv2.waitKey(5000)
        img[0:400,400:800]=(153,0,255)
        cv2.imshow('package',img)
        cv2.waitKey(5000)
        i=i+1

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```